# Htaccess: mod_rewrite (exceptions for certain files)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have already looked through SO and came up with this code, which i think should work, but it does not:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule favicon.png - [NC]
RewriteRule robots.txt - [NC]
RewriteRule sitemap.xml - [NC]
RewriteRule ^static - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Basically everything should be rewritten except for:
favicon.png
robots.txt
everything inside the directory "static"

Part of it works. favicon.png returns the favicon.png file instead of rewriting to index.php. Content inside of "static" is not rewritten as well. But robots.txt and sitemap.xml do not work. I have no idea why.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all of them into single and more correct rule. Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.png|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|static/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```